# Subtracting matrix values with array elements in python

Tags: python

I'm having difficulty sorting a dataset of rbg values in python. I'm wanting to use a greedy heuristic approach, to pick a random rgb valuee, find the shortest Euclidean distance it has with another rgb value and then stick on that rgb value...repeat until all the rbg values are sorted.

I'm getting the following error

```
TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U20') dtype('<U20') dtype('<U20')
```

It's picking a random value correctly, and i think the error is happening because i'm trying to subtract a value such has this (this is what is returned)

```
['0.9664535356921388' '0.4407325991753527' '0.007491470058587191']
```

from a list of rgb values

data set, the first line is the length of the data set. RGB values per colour and this is all stored on a .txt file.

```
10
0.9664535356921388 0.4407325991753527 0.007491470058587191
0.9109759624491242 0.939268997363764 0.5822275730589491
0.6715634814879851 0.08393822683708396 0.7664809327917963
0.23680977536311776 0.030814021726609964 0.7887727172362835
0.3460889655971231 0.6232814750391685 0.6158156951036152
0.14855463870828756 0.18309064740993164 0.11441296968868764
0.014618780486909122 0.48675154060475834 0.9649015609162157
0.06456228097718608 0.5410881855511303 0.46589855900830957
0.6014634495610515 0.08892882999066232 0.5790026861873665
0.26958550381944824 0.5564325605562156 0.6446342341782827
```

script

```
def greedy(colours):
    newcolours = []
    colours  = np.array(colours)
    firstchoice = random.choice(colours)
    print(firstchoice)
    for colour in colours:
     dist = np.linalg.norm(firstchoice - colour)
     shortest = min(dist)
     del(shortest)
     print(shortest)
     newcolours.append(shortest)

def read_file(fname):
    with open(fname, 'r') as afile:
        lines = afile.readlines()
    n = int(lines[3])    # number of colours  in the file
    col = []
    lines = lines[4:]    # colors as rgb values
    for l in lines:
        rgb = l.split()
        col.append(rgb)
    return n, col
```

Comment: [mcve] please...

Comment: I don't think this is the right approach, greedy works fine on 1 dimension but there are 3 and euclidean distance do not point in the same direction. is there something in your code that I'm not seeing to correct for this?